# Sequencing column in Odoo/Openerp

Tags: treeview, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

In Odoo Treeview, I can add a sequencing column like this:

```
<field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
```

The widget handle support auto arrange sequences by drag and drop.
But if I shift the first item to another position, the new first item's sequence isn't 1 but another number. My question is:


1. How can I make the first item's sequence is always 1?

2. Is there any other way to add a sequencing order column in Odoo Treeview? I just want a column to show row num of items.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.model'
    _description = 'test.model'

    sequence = fields.Integer()
    index = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_index')

    @api.one
    def _compute_index(self):
        cr, uid, ctx = self.env.args
        self.index = self._model.search_count(cr, uid, [
            ('sequence', '<', self.sequence)
        ], context=ctx) + 1
```

If you show the field "index" in the tree, it won't change, you have to reload the view :(.